# Append a view in angular instead of replacing with $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Is there some sort of parameter I can set in angular to append views instead of replacing the content?  Something like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute',
  'app.home',
  'app.view2'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/home/index.html',
    controller: 'home',
    replace: false
  });
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
    templateUrl: 'views/view2/index.html',
    controller: 'view2',
    replace: false
  });
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

Ive done some searching but no luck.